# How do you delete individual texts from a message conversation in iOS 8?

Tags: messages

I have downloaded ios8 and I am struggling to delete individual texts from a message conversation. When I open a message and highlight a text bubble, "more" still appears, but when I tick the box, the trash can to delete is missing. The only option given is to click "Delete All". It seems that you have to delete the whole conversation, rather than have the option to select the texts you want to keep/delete within it. Am I missing something? Please advise.

Comment: Bottom left of screen, for me. Delete All is top left.

Comment: There is nothing in the bottom left of my screen other than the camera icon....the bottom line shows camera, message box and send button. Top line is delete all and cancel. The screen will not swipe up, down , left or right.....

Comment: As soon as you tap More, that bottom bar should be replaced by the trash & share buttons. Have you tried restarting the phone?

Answer (score 2):

Press and hold the message to delete, a menu will pop-up with the options "Copy" and "More". Tap "More".

[image: Press and hold the message to delete, select more]

The message you selected is marked with a checkmark on the left. You can check more or delete all by tapping "Delete All" on the top left.

[image: You can select more individual messages if you will, or delete them all]

Tap the trash after selecting the message to be deleted. A confirmation will appear. Press "Delete Message".

[image: After tapping the trash can]

The message is gone. Just blurry messages are left.

[image: Individual message deleted]

Answer (score 0):

"As soon as you tap More, that bottom bar should be replaced by the trash & share buttons."

If this doesn't appear, you can attempt pressing the home button twice to get to the task manager which will let you kill the Messages app, reopen the app, go to the message you want to nuke, press more and the trash button should now appear at the bottom

Alternatively, try restarting.